# query cassandra data with apache solr 6.5.0

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I am new to Solr. I am using solr 6.5.0 and i want to integrate it with cassandra(few details: [cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.17 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]).

The core name is test_core. I have tried to change the details of the solrconfig.xml and managed-schema.xml for test_core so that it can accept data from cassandra, but after i restart solr for reflecting the new changes in test_core, i get the error (simpleposttool: warning: solr returned an error #400 (bad request) for url).

Below are the changes that i have done:
solrconfig.xml

```
<lib dir="/home/retailteg/solr-6.5.0" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-6.5.0.jar" />
  <lib dir="/home/retailteg/solr-6.5.0" regex="cassandra-all-1.2.5.jar" />
  <lib dir="/home/retailteg/solr-6.5.0" regex="cassandra-thrift-1.2.5.jar" />
```

...................................................

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">managed-schema</str>
   </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

managed-schema

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="email" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="password" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

My cassandra table is like below:
id(String), email(String), name(String), password(String)